# Jquery: Using each( ) to change tabular data color based on first character

Tags: jquery, each

I am trying to change the text color in the 4th column of a table based on it's first character. If the first character is a '+', then color should be green. If the first number is a '-', then color should be red, if neither, leave black. Here is the Jquery code I tried to write, but I don't yet have the each() concept nailed down:

```
  $("tr td:eq(3)").each(function (i) {

    if (this.html().charAt(0) == '-') {
        this.css('color' , 'red');
    } 

    if (this.html().charAt(0) == '+') {
        this.css('color' , 'green');
    } 

  });
```

And here is an HTML:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>x</td>
    <td>-10</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>B</td>
    <td>y</td>
    <td>+25</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>C</td>
    <td>z</td>
    <td>66</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code `this` is a plain javascript object, you need `jQuery` object using `$(this)`:

```
var col;
$("tr td:nth-child(4)").each(function(i) {
    col = $(this);
    if (col.html().charAt(0) == '-') {
        col.css('color', 'red');
    }

    if (col.html().charAt(0) == '+') {
        col.css('color', 'green');
    }
});​
```

**Edit**: Your use of `eq` doesn't have the intended effect, i've updated the code using `nth-child`

Comment: That was quick. I just pasted this into my page, but the colors didn't change. Is there another error in the code?

Comment: This still didn't change the 4th column text color. Is there something missing?

Comment: It's working fine as it should, here is a working [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/TfuHQ/)

Comment: This works, but let me ask: why do we need to declare 'col' variable to make '$(this)' work??  Also, I don't have 15 reputation, so I can't raise your score-- thanks though!

Comment: Because you'd have to use `$(this)` multiple times within the `.each` loop. Assigning `$(this)` to `col` makes the whole operation faster, though, in this case, you won't see much difference. It's just basic coding practice, if you're going to use the same thing multiple times, put it in a variable.

Answer (score 2):

I made a slight changes in your code only and this work's as you want.

```
$("tr").each(function () {
    var data = $(this).find("td:eq(3)").text();
    if(data.charAt(0) == '-')
    {
       $(this).find("td:eq(3)").css('color' , 'red');        
    }
    else if(data.charAt(0)== '+')
    {
       $(this).find("td:eq(3)").css('color' , 'green');           
    }
  });
```

Comment: This code made the whole <tr> red and some other cells. But didn't target the 4th column.

Comment: Try now i have changed the target to fourth column now the text color of 4 th column will change.

Comment: Thanks Vivek. I just tested this in jsfiddle, and it does work as well.